# Is Chromium a Linux spyware?

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, chromium, ubuntu-20.04

I've an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS machine and I've installed some application including Chromium and Wireshark. During PC inactivity Wireshark revealed TCP and HTTP connections to a Google LLC server. Is that normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These connections are a part of Chromium's featureset. They are by no means a secret - Chromium's source code is completely open. You can browse it yourself, learn how Chromium interacts with various Google services and make modifications if you wish.

There's also the [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) project which mainly removes Google-dependent features from Chrome and adds some privacy-oriented tweaks.